# How to get access to chosen element of QVector in qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qvector

In cpp file I have property like `QVector<bool> visible1`. I want to initialize property visible in qml. I can't do this like that `visible: visible1[0]`.

How I can get access to chosen element from QVector in qml files?

Comment: How do you expose your vector to QML, using `Q_PROPERTY` ? Through a slot ? Please post more C++ code about your vector.

Comment: Hi, do you get any error message?

Comment: I got **Q_PROPERTY(QVector<bool> visible1 READ get_visible1 WRITE set_visible1 NOTIFY nameVisible1Changed);**. I just have Q_Slot to set_visible1 function. Hmm, i think i must do the same to get_visible1 function and have to pass index like an argument, right? Can i do something like that? @ymoreau

Comment: @derM no it's working, but in qml visible is default set to true even if i have my property set to false.

Comment: Please **edit** your question, to contain some code. It should contain the line `Q_PROPERTY(QVector<bool> visible1 READ get_visible1 WRITE set_visible1 NOTIFY nameVisible1Changed);`, the function `get_visible1`, `set_visible1`, and show how, when, and where you insert values in the QVector.

Comment: Maybe instead of passing a `QVector` build a `QAbstractListModel` that has individual items where each item has a `Q_PROPERTY( bool ...`, of course if that applies to your case, but we see no code to base this on, so it's all just assumptions :)